# Taking value of Array size from user

Tags: c++, arrays

I am doing an assignment for my university course and having the following trouble in my code:

```
cout << "Enter number of values you want to enter" << endl;
int Arraysize;
cin >> Arraysize;

int input_Arr[Arraysize];
```

The compiler gives an array saying that the array size has to be a constant. I have tried dynamically giving an array size, but that gives the same error. The only way it allows a variable as array size is , when the variable is made a const. 
Can you tell me what is the way to get array size from the user and then declare array of that size?
Also , if you do so by dynamic memory allocation, please explain your code at each step.

Comment: Please tag the question with the language you are studying. (Please note C and C++ are different languages.)

Comment: @GSerg hmm I went ahead and tagged it as C++. Now that I saw your comment, I ought to ask whether you think I might be wrong (if so, I should rollback and delete my answer).

Answer (score 4):

Variable sized arrays are not standard C++, thus the compiler is not happy.

You have two options:

1) Use an [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/), which dynamically grows in size automatically. However, since this is HW, you might not be allowed to use it just yet.

2) Use dynamic allocation of memory for your array, by using `new` and `delete`, like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int Arraysize;
  cin >> Arraysize;

  int *input_Arr = new int[Arraysize];

  // Here you have an array called `input_Arr`, of size `Arraysize`, ready to be used (eg filled).

  // when you are done with using the array, you must free the dynamic memory
  delete [] input_Arr;

  return 0;
}
```

The two points that require your attention are:

```
int *input_Arr = new int[Arraysize];
```

What it does? It dynamically allocates memory for an array called `input_Arr`, that will store `int`s. Its size is `Arraysize`.

Every time memory is allocated dynamically, it must gets free'd by the program. To do that, we use this code:

```
delete [] input_Arr;
```

which deletes an array called `input_Arr`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Dynamic allocation in C++, use keywords **new** and **delete**
code for this case will be

```
{
 int size;
 cin>>size;
 int  *my_array = new int[size]; //dynamic allocation
 ...
 delete [] my_array;  //don't forget to use delete at the end of your code

}
```